# VScode maven not executing plugins

Tags: maven, visual-studio-code, maven-javadoc-plugin, maven-source-plugin, maven-gpg-plugin

I am trying to get my library uploaded to the maven central repository using VScode. In order to meet the requierments for that, I have a bunch of plugins configured in my pom.xml file.
Here are all the plugins:

```
       <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.sonatype.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>nexus-staging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.6.7</version>
          <extensions>true</extensions>
          <configuration>
            <serverId>ossrh</serverId>
            <nexusUrl>https://s01.oss.sonatype.org/</nexusUrl>
            <autoReleaseAfterClose>true</autoReleaseAfterClose>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2.1</version>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>attach-sources</id>
              <goals>
                <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.9.1</version>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>attach-javadocs</id>
              <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.5</version>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>sign-artifacts</id>
              <phase>verify</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>sign</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
```

However when I go through the entire maven lifecycle using the VScode maven plugin, no source or javadoc jars are created, and nothing is signed using gpg, what is the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you put the whole section into `<pluginManagement>`, right?

Then it is just a configuration and will not be run.

Move it out of `<pluginManagement>` and it will run as expected.